# What is gc grace in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I was watching DS201 course on Datastax and the lecturer started using the term "GC GRACE" out of nowhere.

What exactly are "GC Grace" and "gc_grace_seconds" ?

Comment: Why someone always needs to downvote a legit question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'gc_grace_seconds' is the time (in seconds, defined in Table properties) cassandra keep Tombstone so that other nodes which might be down during deletion of data can know the changes.

[Go through this link for more](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html)